# Why isn't my zpool listed for export when plugged into new host?

Tags: linux, debian, hard-drive, zfs, zpool

I have a zpool called 'temp' with some data I'm trying to move between systems. I used `zpool export temp` to export the zpool, then I unplugged the disks, and installed them in my new computer. But now when I run `zpool import temp` it just says "cannot import 'temp': no such pool available" and if I try to get a list of zpools available for import with `zpool import` it just says "no pools available to import". The disks are some old 3TB Western Digital spinning rust SATA disks, they are installed properly, and they were working fine in the previous system. Anyone know how I might go about restoring or importing my zpool?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I move a ZFS pool to another computer?](https://serverfault.com/questions/457270/can-i-move-a-zfs-pool-to-another-computer)

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. That says that `zpool import` will work, or maybe require a force with -f, but neither of those commands work for me. I checked the versions as suggested and the system I am importing to has a newer and more capable version of ZFS than the system from which I am importing the data, so that should not be a problem. Not sure why `zpool import` will not work for me.